# How to boot ubuntu, when windows was reinstalled?

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, boot-failure

I installed Ubuntu inside Windows.
Windows was on the C drive. Ubuntu was on the E drive. I reinstalled Windows.
Now Windows is running but Ubuntu does not boot at start up.
How do I recover from this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

More information can be found here- > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

take it easy, all your ubuntu files are still right there on your disk. The main cause of this issue is that windows replaced the bootloader(grub or grub2) on your MBR. All you need to do is to fix(reinstall) grub or grub2(bootloader can be simply considered as a program which lead your system the way to boot OS).

just feel free to visit the link as following, therea are THREE ways to bring your grub back, but make sure you have a ubuntu live CD, you need it to boot to ubuntu first :D

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score -2):

the problem is that you have reinstall and thus "erase" your grub, windows don't recognise Ubuntu what i suggest is to make a clean installation :

1 . put you windows dvd 
format your whole hdd.
2. create 1 partition for your windows and install it
3. insert your  Ubuntu cd then install the os along side with windows.

thats it.

altenative is to in a live cd of linux and install your grub again

hope it help...

Comment: why are asking him to reinstall both the OS? He just need to recover ubuntu.