# Installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation

I have dual boot Vista and ubuntu 11.10
Installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Live CD
A message: Download some applications install manually
Installation completed. Removed the Live CD and restarted.
IT DOES NOT BOOT.
A message GRUB. comes up giving options for startup.
But will not start. 
It starts with the LIVE CD

Please help. ALL my files are in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, here is the similar problem to yours, just jump to the link and check the answers, hope it helps

[How to boot ubuntu, when windows was reinstalled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135857/ubuntu-booting-error/135900)